# Show Snackbar outside of Popup View

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a Popup window where pressing on a button opens a `Snackbar`. I want this Snackbar to show on the bottom of the screen, not on the bottom of the popup window, so I pass the root View to the `Snackbar.make` function instead of the popup view.

The `Snackbar` shows up on the bottom of the screen now, but since the screen behind the popup window is darkened, the snackbar object is also shown behind the gray filter.

I would like to keep this gray layer above the window behind the popup window while showing the snackbar as if it were on the top layer (without the gray filter on it). How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make a `Snackbar` opening function on the fragment or activity, then when you instantiate the `PopupView` you pass the method through a listener.